# Unable to generate documentation with grape-swagger

Tags: swagger, ruby-grape

I am trying to generate the documentation with grape-swagger.

On my gem file

```
gem 'grape-entity'
gem 'grape-swagger'
gem 'grape-swagger-entity'
gem 'grape-swagger-rails'
```

On my endpoint

```
require 'grape-swagger'
module MyModule
  class Api < Grape::API
    content_type :json, 'application/json'
    default_format :json
    format :json

    mount V1::Root
    add_swagger_documentation
  end
end
```

When I am visiting http://localhost:3000/swagger_doc I am getting an error,

`No route matches [GET] "/swagger_doc".`

Also I don't see any doc generated.

Answer (score 2):

add the prefix if you have mounted a place other than root.

for example /api/swagger_doc